# How to get and pass hash-table in define-condition object?

Tags: common-lisp

I'm trying to print the error message of a define-condition that I created:

```
(defun is-t? (actual)
  (assertion (create-result (equal t actual) actual t 'equal)))

(defun create-result (result actual expected operator)
  (let ((assert-result (make-hash-table)) (message))
    (setf message (concatenate 'string (string actual) " " (string operator) " " (string expected)))
    (setf (gethash 'result assert-result) result)
    (setf (gethash 'actual assert-result) actual)
    (setf (gethash 'expected assert-result) expected)
    (setf (gethash 'message assert-result) message)
    assert-result))

(defun assertion (assert-result)
  (unless (gethash 'result assert-result)
    (error 'assertion-error :message (gethash 'message assert-result))))

(define-condition assertion-error (error)
  ((message :initarg :message :reader error-message)))
```

What I am trying to do is the following, an assertion library where I can throw an error when there is a failure, for a test runner to capture it and use the object that is the hash-table to signal where it is wrong. I do not know how to pass this has-table into error, could I pass on :message? I imagine it is not recommended. And how do I redeem it later or even a :message?

An example trying to catch an error:

```
CL-USER> (handler-case (is-t? nil) 
    (assertion-error (c) 
      (format t "~a" c)))
Condition COMMON-LISP-USER::ASSERTION-ERROR was signalled.
NIL
```

How do I access :message and how would I pass hash-table to access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I access :message ?

You access it either with its `:reader` or `:accessor`. Here, you can do `(error-message c)`.

An accessor is both a "getter" and a "setter". I invite you to read more about the object system here: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/clos.html#getters-and-setters-accessor-reader-writer

> how would I pass hash-table to access it?

Conditions are not strictly classes but very similar in practice. We can define many slots with their corresponding reader, writer or accessor, we are not restricted to a `message` slot. So as said by Svante, instead of storing a hash-table, just store the information you want in other slots. Or create a "result" slot to which you give a hash-table, it's also possible.

```
(define-condition assertion-error (error)
  ((message :initarg :message :reader error-message)
   (expected :initarg :expected :accessor assertion-expected)
   (actual …)
   (result …))
  (:report …))
```

To set "expected": `(setf (assertion-expected c) <value>)`.

The `:report` is what is displayed in the debugger: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/error_handling.html#defining-and-making-conditions

Comment: I would like to thank the answer, it helped me, but it was still a question, it is possible to leave a default value, example of an imaginary configuration of default value **t** to **actual**:`(actual :initarg :actual :reader (actual t))`?

Comment: yes that will be `:initform t`: see the Cookbook on CLOS.

Answer (score 3):

In order to change the output, you need to override the reporting function:

```
(define-condition assertion-error (error)
  ((expected :initarg :expected :reader assertion-expected)
   (actual :initarg :actual :reader assertion-actual))
  (:report (lambda (condition stream)
             (format stream
                     "Assertion failed.  Expected ~s but got ~s instead."
                     (assertion-expected condition)
                     (assertion-actual condition)))))
```

As you see, you do not need an extra hash-table.  The condition object already provides named slots etc.  This is also where you'd do the formatting, so you need not format the message at the throwing point.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, as long as the message is formed within the error, it would not be good, because it would be too generic a "but got" instead of a possible "equal" or "unless" or what can be.